# Show browser upgrade warning for IE8, IE7, IE6 in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, internet-explorer, browser

I am developing Wordpress website. But most of function not displayed in IE8 browser. So i planed to show browser upgrading warning but its not working. Could any one help me.

```
<script> 
var $buoop = {vs:{i:9,f:15,o:12.1,s:5.1},c:2}; 
function $buo_f(){ 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.js"; 
 document.body.appendChild(e);
};
try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//browser-update.org/update.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can load your javascript file from conditional comment, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    <!--[if IE 5]>
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
alert ("It looks like you aren't using Internet Explorer 7. To see our site correctly, please update.")
//-->
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5.0]>
!--
alert ("It looks like you aren't using Internet Explorer 7. To see our site correctly, please update.")
//-->
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5.5]>
!--
alert ("It looks like you aren't using Internet Explorer 7. To see our site correctly, please update.")
//-->
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
!--
alert ("It looks like you aren't using Internet Explorer 7. To see our site correctly, please update.")
//-->
</script>
<![endif]-->
```